# Improving my guessing game

Tags: java

i'm currently working on a Guessing game , and i got it to work ( i would really appreciate it , if someone tests it out and comments what they think i will link my GitHub repo at the bottom of the post ) but i still have a little problem , when the user enters an illegal guess (higher than the maximum number of items in the jar or lower than 1 ) an IllegalArgumentException gets thrown (like i designed it to ) but the program stops prompting the user to guess , and i wasn't able to figure out on my own how to make it continue prompting .If someone can help me i'll really appreciate it . Another side question i have about the project is , what is meant by "encapsulating the I/O in a prompter class " ? I made a Prompter , but i'm not sure if the implementation is really good and if someone has any ideas how i can improve this program in general , i would really love to hear them.

this is the program : https://github.com/Melodie95/Treehouse-Project-1-

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it necessary to throw a IllegalArgumentException could you not use if else to check whether the input is valid or not if not then simply print the error message and let the program goes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of 2 things could be done here either replacing the exception throwing with something else which would be something like this:

inside Game.main() change this:

```
try{
    jar.guess();

} catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
    System.out.println("Please choose a valid number");
}
```

to this:

```
jar.guess();
```

simply eliminating the try catch check and inside Jar.guess() change this:

```
if(guess>maxNumberOfItems){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
} else if (guess<1){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

to this:

// the || means logical OR, if either of the 2 conditions is true than the if will read true in this case

```
if(guess>maxNumberOfItems || guess<1){
    System.out.println("Please choose a valid number");
}
```

however if you're using exceptions to learn exceptions  than the reason you are having the issue is because of 2 things
first off - when the exception occurs in guess() but isn't caught java's exception system checks to see if guess() expects to be throwing exceptions which in your case it doesn't, which means the exception never leaves guess() and the exception errors out and your try catch never sees the exception.
The way you tell a method to pass along any exceptions of a certain type is to put the keyword throws followed by the types of exceptions it should pass along between the () and the opening { of the method head like this:

```
public void guess() throws IllegalArgumentException {
```

but that only allows your current try catch to see the exception and stops the program from erroring out

in order to get it to keep prompting for guesses over and over the try catch in this case has to be inside the while loop that causes the repeated guessing in the first place. To do this you can either put the try catch in guess()

```
while(guess != numberOfItems){
    try{
        if(guess>maxNumberOfItems){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (guess<1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
        System.out.println("Please choose a valid number");
    }

    prompter.tryAgain();
    guess = scanner.nextInt();
    numberOfGuesses++;
}
```

or you can add the throws IllegalArgumentException clause to guess() and move the while loop (and some of the variables that store things like number of guesses) outside of guess() to have guess() called once for each guess instead of once per game

for more info about the throws clause check oracle's java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)